# Semicolon separate column of values

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have a file with two columns: `A` and `B`. `A` is irrelevant to what I want to do here.

I am new to Excel. How do I bring together all the values in `B` with separation by semicolons?

For example, from:

> B1 = 123
>   B2 = 345
>   B3 = 343

I want `123;345;343`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=CONCATENATE(B1,";",B2,";",B3,";")
```

would work for a small number of values

For a large number of values you would have to write a macro or function.

Answer (score 1):

For almost unlimited numbers I'd suggest copying ColumnB into Word as unformatted text, replace pilcrow `¶` with `;` and copy back in to Excel.